# Zenmuse XT mobile SDK UI

Tags: dji-sdk

I have several different cameras that I'm attaching to LB2 and A3. The X3, Z3 and XT 640 Radiometric. I'm having one heck of a time trying to figure out why the UI widgets especially the CameraControlsWidget is not updating to the correct camera setting menus when the XT is attached. I'm also noticing that the FPVOverlayWidget and FPVOverlay are not carrying over OSD options like spot metering.

Whats the issue with this? I have looked through all of the online documentation for the Android Mobile UI and I do not see anything called out specifically for the XT. This lead me to believe it would enable and disable options by camera type when they are connected.

Am I missing something? or does the UI for the XT have to be built by the developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. DJI is currently working on a fix for this.

Comment: Thank you Sara! Do you by any chance have any links to where DJI has acknowledged this? I don't doubt you I just want to read up on what they have to say.

Comment: Sara works at DJI, she's an engineer in the Android SDK team. And I know this because I run Developer Technologies at DJI :)

Comment: Fantastic! That's good to hear!! Nice to see the DJI teams reaching out directly! Thank you!